# How can I run helm upgrade on velero deployment?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, velero

Whenever I try to run helm upgrade on velero deployment in kubernetes(AKS) it tries to delete the CRDs of velero and fails after deleting some.

```
helm upgrade velero vmware-tanzu/velero --namespace velero \
  --set-file credentials.secretContents.cloud=./credentials-velero \
  --set configuration.provider=azure \
  --set configuration.backupStorageLocation.name=azure \
  --set configuration.backupStorageLocation.bucket='velero' \
  --set configuration.backupStorageLocation.config.resourceGroup=us-dev \
  --set configuration.backupStorageLocation.config.storageAccount=store1 \
  --set snapshotsEnabled=true \
  --set deployRestic=true \
  --set configuration.volumeSnapshotLocation.name=azure \
  --set configuration.volumeSnapshotLocation.config.resourceGroup=us-dev \
  --set image.repository=velero/velero \
  --set image.pullPolicy=Always \
  --set initContainers[0].name=velero-plugin-for-microsoft-azure \
  --set initContainers[0].image=velero/velero-plugin-for-microsoft-azure:master \
  --set initContainers[0].volumeMounts[0].mountPath=/target \
  --set initContainers[0].volumeMounts[0].name=plugins
```

I even tried using following option but still same error

```
--reuse-values
```

Am I doing it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I used [Install Velero with HELM in GCP](https://medium.com/@ct.ics2009/install-velero-with-helm-in-gcp-15b7a0186ae) to install and test before answering you. So you can find my `Values.yaml` content from the article.

Successful installation was performed by `helm install vmware-tanzu/velero --name velero --namespace velero -f Values.yaml --version 2.8.7 --set imageTag=1.2.0`

And answering your question , I was able to upgrade `velero` using same command as you

```
helm upgrade velero vmware-tanzu/velero --namespace velero --reuse-values \
  --set image.pullPolicy=IfNotPresent
```

Unfortunately havent checked on Azure.
Please add more details/logs, specify what exact CRDs you are not able to remove.

Comment: following are the crd  that helm upgrade tries to delete                                                                                                    **backups.velero.io
backupstoragelocations.velero.io
deletebackuprequests.velero.io
downloadrequests.velero.io 
podvolumebackups.velero.io
podvolumerestores.velero.io
resticrepositories.velero.io
restores.velero.io
schedules.velero.io
serverstatusrequests.velero.io
volumesnapshotlocations.velero.io**

Comment: when I run helm upgrade it fails with Error upgrade failed, unable to delete **backupstoragelocations.velero.io**